# How to stop a blinking div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm using the below jquery way to blink my div:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Vaysf/1/)

```
<div class="blink">blinking text</div>non-blinking
<div class="blink">more blinking text</div>
```

```js
function blink(selector){
    $(selector).fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $(this).fadeIn('slow', function(){
            blink(this);
        });
    });
}

blink('.blink');
```

But how do we stop it from blinking? I just want it to blink for 5 times only.

Comment: Use a counter. Check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/L0pz9t9w/)

Comment: Please post the code here as well. It guarantee future visitors to this question will be able to see this code even if the code is gone from that link (for whatever reason).

Comment: try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342485/how-to-stop-a-blinking-div/33342640#33342640

Comment: What if I got more div to blink. Is it that I have to create a counter for each div?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with CSS alone, no need for Javascript:

```
@-webkit-keyframes blinker {
    0% { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.0; }
    100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}
.blink {
    -webkit-animation: blinker 1s 5;
    -moz-animation: blinker 1s 5;
    animation: blinker 1s 5;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vaysf/865/)

Note the `5` value at the end of the statement is the `animation-iteration-count`. You can amend this as required.

Comment: Yup.. how do we call this function?

Comment: @Coolguy what do you mean how do you call the function? It's CSS. Check the fiddle for a working example.

Comment: Using css means that after the div is ready, it will blink 5 times right? No need call the function... But what if I want the same div to re-blink another 5 times?

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution,

Try This

```
var i = 0;

function blink(selector) {
    $(selector).fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $(this).fadeIn('slow', function () {
            i++ < 8 && blink(this);
        });

    });
}

blink('.blink');
```

here is the demo: 
[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/amrindernoor/29se1efw/)

Comment: this seems to be an easy way to solve the issue, nice.

Comment: What if I got more div to blink. Is it that I have to create a counter for each div?

Comment: no, you just have to set same class (.blink) to new divs, this way you can add as many divs as you want

Comment: But my application is that the all div does not start blink at the same time. they start blink at different time. For example if total bllinking for all div is 5 times, then after my div1 start blink, then after div1 blink for 2 times, div2 start blink.. then div2 will blink for 3 times only because of the same counter value now left 3 times only.

Comment: then you must have create some logic by yourself, stack-overflow is to guide you not to create logic for you.